# Highcharts set xaxis value from array

Tags: php, arrays, highcharts

I need to setup some Xaxis values from array in Highcharts.

```
print_r($monthName);
```

I have array: `Array ( [0] => August [1] => September [2] => October [3] => November [4] => December [5] => January )`.

My code is:

```
<script>
$(function () {
var monthNameData = [];
    monthNameData.push({
        data: ['<?php echo join ($monthName, ',') ?>']
    });

    $('#iw').highcharts({
        chart: {
            ...
        xAxis: {
           categories: monthNameData[0].data
        },
        series: ...
    });
});
```

My result is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTggV.jpg)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct like below

**Either**

```
monthNameData.push({
    data: <?php echo json_encode($monthName); ?>
});
```

**OR**

```
monthNameData.push({
       data: [<?php echo "'".join($monthName, "','")."'"; ?>]
});
```